# Mutably borrowing fields of struct results in an apparent contradiction in compiler error message

Tags: rust

I'm having some trouble understanding the compiler error message for this code:

```
struct A {
    b: B,
    c: C,
}
struct B {
    f: u32,
}
struct C {
    f: u32,
}

fn foo(b: &mut B) -> &u32 { &b.f }
fn bar(c: &mut C) -> &u32 { &c.f }
fn quux(z: &mut A) -> u32 { z.b.f }

fn baz(a: &mut A) {
    let x = foo(&mut a.b);
    let y = bar(&mut a.c);
    let z = quux(a); // equivalent to: quux(&mut *a)
    println!("{} {}", x, y);
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*a` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:22:18
   |
20 |     let x = foo(&mut a.b);
   |                 -------- first mutable borrow occurs here
21 |     let y = bar(&mut a.c);
22 |     let z = quux(a);
   |                  ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
23 |     println!("{} {}", x, y);
   |                       - first borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

If line 20 is mutably borrowing `*a` (as the compilation error asserts), then line 21 must also mutably borrow `*a` (How couldn't it? It's nearly identical to line 20 -- only difference is which field is borrowed), so by my reasoning the code should still fail to compile after deleting line 22; however, the code actually compiles just fine if I delete line 22. The fact that this would then compile seems to contradict the compiler's claim that `&mut a.b` results in a mutable borrow of `*a`.

`x` and `y` are immutable borrows, so if anything I would expect a compilation error regarding the overlapping scopes of the immutable `x`/`y` and the mutable borrow of `*a` in line 22 (otherwise `quux` could conceivably mutate `a` while we're borrowing its fields).

What knowledge am I likely missing that makes this error message confusing to me? If you're not surprised by this message, could you break down how you reason about this?

---

Some more thinking before I submitted this question:

I suppose the immutable references returned from `foo` and `bar` somehow extend the original mutable borrows of `a.b` and `a.c` (why that would be necessary, I don't know). If that's the case, maybe the way to see this is that `&mut a.b` and `&mut a.c` in turn extend the mutable borrow of `*a`. The error message says the first mutable borrow of `*a` occurs on line 20, but maybe the way to see this is:

- The true first borrow of `*a` is when when the caller gives us the `&mut A`.
- While the compiler suggests there's a mutable borrow of `*a` on line 20, this isn't exactly the case: the `mut &a.b` expression borrows `(*a).b`, but merely *extends* the existing borrow given to us (as opposed to being a *new* mutable borrow of `*a`).
- The last point, but with respect to `mut &a.c`.
- Insert the aforementioned reasoning of "extending borrows" wrt `*a`.
- The call to `quux` then mutably borrows the `*a` a second time.

So maybe what the compilation error calls the initial borrow of `*a` is actually reporting the location of the expression responsible for extending the original `*a` borrow?

Answer (score 4):

Line 20 does not conflict with 21 since they borrow different fields within `a` and therefore cause no collision.

The issue is that `foo` and `bar` return references that inherit the lifetime of the mutable reference. Even though they return immutable references, their lifetimes rely on the lifetime of the mutable borrow. So by requiring they live for a period of time, by extension the mutable borrow must do so as well. The compiler always takes the function signature on face value so it can not downgrade the initial mutable reference. If it did not, it could lead to issues if the function was modified later or if it contained unsafe code that relied on consuming a mutable reference for safety.

Here is a counter example where all of the function signatures remain the same. Since the compiler can not make assumptions on how `quux` and `foo` will use their values `quux` may make the references returned by `foo` or `bar` invalid.

```rust
struct A {
    b: B,
    c: C,
}
struct B {
    f: Option<u32>,
}
struct C {
    f: u32,
}


fn foo(b: &mut B) -> &u32 { 
    b.f.as_ref().unwrap()
}

fn bar(c: &mut C) -> &u32 { &c.f }

fn quux(z: &mut A) -> u32 {
    z.b.f = None;
    z.c.f
}

fn baz(a: &mut A) {
    let x = foo(&mut a.b);
    let y = bar(&mut a.c);
    let z = quux(a);
    println!("{} {}", x, y);
}
```

Comment: "Line 20 does not conflict with 21 since they borrow different fields within a and therefore cause no collision." -- that does make sense to me. But part of my confusion stems from the way the error is worded -- as if line 20 is itself borrowing `*a`, which would entail the same of line 21. So maybe the error message is just poorly worded?

Comment: "The issue is that foo and bar return references that inherit the lifetime of the mutable reference." -- ah, that makes sense. The Rust Book makes some reference to the "scope" of (im)mutable reference and the rules thereof, but I suppose what the compiler is actually checking (when we speak of "multiple mutable references coexisting") is whether the lifetimes of these references overlap.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here. First: why does `let x = foo(&mut a.b);` prevent you from doing `let z = quux(a);`, and second why does `let x = foo(&mut a.b);` *not* prevent you from doing `let y = bar(&mut a.c);`?

##### Why does `let x = foo(&mut a.b);` prevent you from doing `let z = quux(a);`?

This is due to the [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html). You declared `foo` as:

```
fn foo(b: &mut B) -> &u32
```

Since you use references there must be a lifetime, but since you didn't specify one yourself the compiler assumes that all references have the same lifetime. In other words, the compiler rewrites your code as:

```
fn foo<'a>(b: &'a mut B) -> &'a u32
```

Which means that the returned value has the same lifetime as the mutable borrow, so the mutable borrow lasts until the `println` where you use the return value `x`, which prevents other borrows of `a.b` or `a` as a whole.

##### But then why does `let x = foo(&mut a.b);` *not* prevent you from doing `let y = bar(&mut a.c);`?

That's because the compiler is smart enough to realize that `a.b` and `a.c` are disjoint parts of `a`, which can be borrowed without conflict (in the same way that you can borrow different local variables simultaneously).

Comment: "That's because the compiler is smart enough to realize that a.b and a.c are disjoint parts of a, which can be borrowed without conflict" -- that part makes sense to me.

Comment: However, could you explain the (apparent to me) contradiction in the error message? When the compiler says "first mutable borrow occurs here", it doesn't explicitly state _which_ reference, but because it makes no explicit mention of any other borrow, it would seem it is referring to the aforementioned borrow in the "cannot borrow `*a` as mutable more than once at a time" error message, which would entail that line 21 also mutably borrows `*a` (I mean, that's not what _I'm_ claiming -- that's what the compiler seems to be suggesting, at least with the way the error message is worded).

Comment: Borrowing `a.b` counts as partially borrowing `a`. When you call `quux(a)`, the compiler checks if `a` is already borrowed (partially or in full) and so errors out by saying that (at least part of) `a` is borrowed. Note that if you try to borrow `a.b` again, the [error will be more specific and mention only `a.b`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ff92284ab20dc47ae30a39886bb0f92c).